# Parsing words fron string to array

Tags: php, preg-match

I have some searsh results like this

```
$search = 'an';
```

and some string that has many text like this

```
$text = 'Anda goes wiwsh totot anaana here goes like this <p>helle</p><b>an</b>Kako isyaay an koliko ana an here <div>hello ana</div>';
```

You will see there are a lots of words that have **an**

I need to go in that string and find only word that contained the search results and put in array, of course i dont need html inside, my final array must look like this

```
$results = array ('Anda','anaana','an','an','ana','an','ana');
```

Comment: Not too sure, but are you looking for something like this: https://3v4l.org/Z4Gka ?

Comment: I have PHP version 5.2, this does not work?

Comment: I need only one array, with results

Comment: It should also work with PHP 5.2, (just changed the capturing group, to see the result better): https://3v4l.org/7Cj8R

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$all_words = explode(' ', strip_tags($text));

$results = array();

foreach ($all_words as $word) {
    if (substr($search, $word) !== FALSE) {
        $results[] = $word;
    }
}
```

Note that because of the way your text is formatted, the array will include 'helleanKako' rather than 'an' in that one case.

Comment: That can be problem :(

Comment: There's not much that can be done about it without using a much more complicated tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

Strrchr can return true when found match character,...

```
<?php
$search = "an";
$text = 'Anda goes wiwsh totot anaana here goes like this <p>helle</p><b>an</b>Kako isyaay an koliko ana an here <div>hello ana</div>';
$all_words = explode(' ', $text);

$results = array();

foreach ($all_words as $word) {
if (strrchr($word,$search) == TRUE) {
    $results[] = $word;
} 
}
var_dump($results);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too late... :

```
<?php
$input = 'Anda goes wiwsh totot anaana here goes like this <p>helle</p><b>an</b>Kako isyaay an koliko ana an here <div>hello ana</div>';
$pattern = '/([^\s^>]*an[^\s^<]*)/i';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches)){
    print_r($matches);
}
?>

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Anda
            [1] => anaana
            [2] => an
            [3] => an
            [4] => ana
            [5] => an
            [6] => ana
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Anda
            [1] => anaana
            [2] => an
            [3] => an
            [4] => ana
            [5] => an
            [6] => ana
        )

)
```

Hope that's what you've expected